# Linux mint mate 20 installation on dell computer. Giving the "nouveau 0000:01:00.0: tmr: stalled at ffffffffffffffff" error

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation, nouveau

I have been trying to install linux mint on my dell laptop, using a bootable flash usb (I am a newbie). I am not sure what went wrong, after I selected the 'start linux mint' option I saw a screen with a bunch of messages written on it.
After sometime it kept repeating this message over and over; [some number] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: tmr: stalled at ffffffffffffffff

Can it be that the machine I am trying to run this one is rather new and compatible with MATE 20? I am using a DELL Inspiron 15 5510. It has a NVIDIA GeForce MX450 graphic card. (also this piece of info maybe utterly useless but the usb i am using is a 32GB one, I converted it to a flash usb using Universal Usb Installer.)

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=248787
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1874624
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-nouveau/-/issues/516

Comment: @gapsf so it is an issue with the graphic card/driver? also I went through some linux mint forums and someone recommended compatibility mode..... can this work?